# Dynamic query conditions Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, filtering, slick-3.0

I am trying to filter a table with parameters that can be optional. With slick 2.1 this worked, but when I go to version 3.0 no longer works, the error is: "can not resolve symbol &&" when I call the function "reduce".

I would appreciate any help .. thank you very much

This is the code:

```
def getAll(params : ClienteSearchParameters) : DBIOAction[Iterable[Cliente], NoStream, Effect.Read] = {

      val q = for {
        (x, (y, z)) <- tabla join (tablaPersonas joinLeft tablaContactos on (_.id === _.idPersona)) on (_.idPersona === _._1.id)
          if {
            List(
                params.nombre.map(y.nombre === _),
                params.apellido.map(y.apellido === _),
                params.fechaAlta.map(x.fechaAlta === _),
                params.fechaRegistracion.map(x.fechaRegistracion === _)
            ).flatten match {
              case Nil => LiteralColumn[Boolean](true)
              case seq => seq.reduce(_ && _)
            }
          }
      } yield (x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is info from doc http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#sorting-and-filtering

I guess you can find here what you want. The example from doc:

```
//building criteria using a "dynamic filter" e.g. from a webform. 
val criteriaColombian = Option("Colombian")
val criteriaEspresso = Option("Espresso")
val criteriaRoast:Option[String] = None

val q4 = coffees.filter { coffee => 
  List(
      criteriaColombian.map(coffee.name === _),
      criteriaEspresso.map(coffee.name === _),
      criteriaRoast.map(coffee.name === _) // not a condition as `criteriaRoast` evaluates to `None` 
  ).collect({case Some(criteria)  => criteria}).reduceLeftOption(_ || _).getOrElse(true:Column[Boolean])
}
```

Comment: I found the error, both solutions work, the problem is that both "y.apellido" and "x.fechaAlta" are colums option, then the symbol && is not found. If I use the method "getOrElse" it works well but not sure it is the best way ..

Comment: You can try something like this:
params.apellido.flatMap(v => y.apellido.map(v === y)),

Comment: Hi igor, this dont work.... i tried too with:  params.apellido.map(v => y.apellido.map(v === _)), ... but i get an Option[Rep[Option[Boolean]]]... and this should be a Option[Rep[Boolean]].. then i get the some error... "cannot resolve symbol && "

Comment: I could solve it!  doing the following: params.apellido.map (x => persona.apellido.map (_ === x) .getOrElse (false))

Comment: @JuanPabloVittori your last solution could generate boilerplate SQL code like:  `where (case when ((case when (x2.`order` is null) then null else (x2.`order` = 20) end) is null) then true else (case when (x2.`order` is null) then null else (x2.`order` = 20) end) end)`